# "Gotta" pronunciation

Tags: american-english, abbreviations, flapping

Recently, I realized that pronunciations of the reduction *gotta* in GB and US English are different.

Could you suggest to me, please, any tutorial explaining pronunciation of this and other such shortenings? It would be nice to find something with audio also. Usual textbooks avoid this subject since it is related to informal language, and it is very hard for me to get correct pronunciation from movies or TV series.

Comment: Don't have time to get into a full answer but what you're referring to is glottalisation. English: "gotta". Cockney/Estuary English: "go'a". American English: "godda". It's not because it's a shortening, but rather how the accents interact with the words. You'll find the same thing with "bottle" and "pitter-patter", for example.

Comment: @Samthere That comment is easily enough for an answer, and I'd upvote it. You should post. You can always come back and edit it for thoroughness later.

Comment: Try a dictionary like [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/gotta) for pronunciation audio :)

Comment: Tell me more about "it is very hard for me to get correct pronunciation from movies or TV series."  Is it because it goes by too quickly?  If so, I would suggest podcasts.  You can slow them down 20%.  You can hit "pause" whenever you need to.  You can back up and listen again.  I think the best kind would be the ones that come with a transcript.  Here's one possibility: Democracy Now.  I believe they post full transcripts along with the podcasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound we use for this in American English is the alveolar flap.  Knowing this name should help you find references that will help you (c.f. Wikipedia, for example).

I think of this substitution of the flap for both voiced and voiceless alveolar plosives between vowels in casual speech as a form of assimilation where we simplify the pronunciation into something very close to a liquid.

Answer (score 2):

if you are searching for a direct Britain/American pronunciation, I get you this advise: try with wordreference.com
You can choose between the two ways. There are not all the words, but surely the most important