# So, we don't change /t/ to /d/ if /t/ is between 2 vowel sounds and /t/ is the beginning of the stressed sound in a word in American English, right?

Tags: pronunciation, flapping

Ok, see this word **entertainment** has IPA of `/en.təˈteɪn.mənt/`. Ok, now in American English if /t/ is between 2 vowel sounds  then it will become /d/ cos it is flap T.

But /t/ will become flap T only if the sound in the word is not stressed. Is that correct?

For example, for the above example, we can pronounce `/en.dəˈteɪn.mənt/` but not `/en.dəˈdeɪn.mənt/`, right?

Comment: In AmE we're more likely to drop the consonant altogether. Entertainment becomes /en.əɻˈteɪn.mənt/

Comment: @Robusto: but we only drop the first /t/ because that /t/ is after an /n/, and not between two vowel sounds.

Comment: The rule is intermedial unstressed. so 'letter' -> /'le der/, but 'deter' -> /dij 'ter/

Comment: Probable duplicate of one or more of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/13980, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68634, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/64828, http://english.stackexchange.com/a/226203, http://english.stackexchange.com/a/110766, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/226213, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/110741, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/105011, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/112549, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/142718, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/102624, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/233751, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56108.

Comment: Actually, a t will flap before a stressed vowel, provided that the t is at the end of a syllable.  When t and the following stressed vowel are within the same word, the t is never at the end of a syllable, so it never flaps.  However, when the following stressed vowel is in a different word, then the t remains in the same syllable as the preceding vowel, and it will flap, provided other conditions on flapping are met.

Comment: You’re leaving out the R. You shouldn’t do that. We don’t talk that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

t/d/n become flaps when they are (1) after a vowel or glide (including r but not l), (2) before a vowel, and (3) at the end of a syllable.  (Condition (3) is stated with the assumption that an intervocalic consonant before an unstressed vowel goes at the end of the preceding syllable.)

"Entertainment" has a rather involved derivation.  After nasalizing the preceding vowel, the first n is lost by a rule that deletes nasal consonants before voiceless consonants at the same place of articulation.  The first t is now between vowels and at the end of a syllable, so it flaps.  The flap assimilates in voice to the preceding and following voiced vowels, and being a sonorant consonant, it also assimilates in nasality to the preceding nasal vowel, so we wind up with a nasal voiced flap between the first two vowels of "entertainment".  Nothing remarkable happens in the "tainment" part of the word, except [n] optionally assimilates in position to following [m].

This follows the phonological treatment worked out a long time ago by my teacher David Stampe.  Note that there is never a d at any stage of the derivation, and there is never an intervocalic n, either.

## [ɛ̃ɾ̃ɹ̩̃tʰej̃mmə̃nt̚]

Comment: BRAVO! The punchline at the bottom is so well done you should put a `#` in front of it so it gets all big and bold. :)

Comment: Should the last /n/ not also be deleted before the homorganic /t/? I definitely don't have an actual [n] at the end before the unreleased [t̚] in normal speech. I presume the nasal deletion rule (apart from being optional) is more conditioned than you explain here—it doesn't apply in words like _hamper_ or _until_, for example, but can apply in _bonkers_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, yes, it seems the last [n] should be lost.  But in my own speech, it isn't.  I don't know why. (I wrote schwa, but maybe it's syllabic [n].)  In *until*, I think the [n] being in a different syllable than the [t] makes the deletion less applicable.  I can delete [m] in *hamper* -- I don't know why it's not lost for you.

Answer (score 3):

As an American, I would say I pronounce the word quite differently than your rendition:

> en'-ter-teɪn'-ment

With both "t" sounds.   However, please note, neither is actually between two vowel sounds.  A better example would be letter.

> led'-er